# Image src in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

Is there a difference between these?

`<img src="{{url}}">`

`<img [src]="url">`

I know in AngularJS we had `ng-src` directive which was prefered to used to prevent loading image from `{{url}}` before angular takes over. Is this the same case?

Comment: It achieves the same result. `[src]` is not a known HTML attribute due to the `[]`s, so the browser will *not* process it and will *not* make a request to the URL. It's really easy to [try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lf1chug/) by just running the HTML you provided with different URLs and checking the network requests in your developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img [src]="heroImageUrl">
```

is short of

```
<img bind-src="heroImageUrl">
```

this code will result same as `<img src="{{url}}">`. `[src]` this is for property binding. However when you need to bind some data to attribute you cannot use it. For example:

```
<td [attr.colspan]="1 + 1">
```

since colspan is not a property but html attribute.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment lead me to this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property

Comment: well seems like i am mistaken. <td colspan={{someVar}}> doesn't work as well.

Comment: after reding through docs I would expect it to work. Strange.